# An algebraic stack as a non-linear analog of a complex of vector spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, schemes, tangent-spaces, algebraic-stacks

In their paper [Derived Quot Schemes](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_2001_4_34_3_403_0.pdf) Kapranov and Ciocane-Fontanine write in the introduction:

> Indeed, an algebraic stack is a nonlinear analog of a complex of vector spaces situated in degrees $[-1,0]$ and, for example, the tangent "space" to a stack at a point is a complex of this nature.

Can someone explain this analogy? Pointers to the literature would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long story and I don't know what the shortest way to tell it is. Here's one version: you can think of an algebraic stack as being, at least locally, presented by a [groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid) [internal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) to schemes. E.g. if we consider a quotient stack $X/G$ then the corresponding groupoid is the action groupoid $G \times X \rightrightarrows X$ where the two arrows are the action map resp. the projection; I will stick to this example from now on.

Now what should the "tangent space" to such a thing be? You can imagine taking a point $x \in X$ and considering taking the tangent space at $x$ in the base space $X$ and also at $(e, x)$ in $G \times X$; together we get a groupoid $\mathfrak{g} \times T_x(X) \rightrightarrows T_x(X)$ internal to vector spaces (if we're working in schemes over a field, say), also known as a [Baez-Crans $2$-vector space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-vector+space#BaezCrans2VectorSpaces).

Now it is a pleasant exercise to check that the category of groupoids internal to vector spaces is equivalent to the category of two-term chain complexes of vector spaces (and "vector spaces" can be replaced by any abelian category). This is a simplified version of the [Dold-Kan correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Kan_correspondence) and is explained, for example, in Baez and Crans' *[Higher-Dimensional Algebra VI: Lie $2$-Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307263)*, Proposition 8. I think but have not checked carefully that if we apply this correspondence to the above example we should get the two-term chain complex $\mathfrak{g} \to T_x(X)$ where the map is the differential of the map $G \ni g \mapsto gx \in X$ at $g = e$.

More generally we can talk about [higher stacks](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+stack). These look, again at least locally, like [simplicial schemes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+scheme), so their "tangent spaces" look like simplicial vector spaces and these correspond to longer chain complexes by the full Dold-Kan correspondence. The Dold-Kan correspondence generally suggests the intuition that simplicial objects are "nonlinear chain complexes."

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Will try to study it in detail the next days.